# Publish test utils from maven project

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, hamcrest

I created a library in maven that can be extended by implementing some interfaces. To test the default implementation I have written some hamcrest matchers that currently live in `src/test/java`.

However, I think they might be useful for users of the library if they want to test their customization.

So how can I make them available? Moving them to `src/main` would require to make hamcrest a runtime dependency and I don't want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to create a test jar and install it into the repository using the command 'mvn jar:test-jar'.  This jar can then be referenced by other projects using the test-jar modifier in the dependency block.

If you want to have this jar built and installed as part of your your normal 'mvn install' build add the following plugin config to your pom:

From http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.2</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then other projects can reference the test jar as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, move it to src/main in a new project. Let that project only be used in a test dependency and you don't pollute your module's classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to move them to their own project and release it. From there you can determine in the original project what scope you'd like.

Comment: But that would lead to circular dependencies, wouldn't it?

Comment: This is the solution I have been using. I am not sure where would be a circular dependency?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can always declare the proposed circular dependencies as scope provided or exclude them on the project that depends on it. There are lots of ways around this.

Comment: The test-util project would depend on the main project and the main projects test will depend on test-util. To make sure I got it right, you are saying the best way to resolve this is to have test-util depend on main as "provided"?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. It definitely doesn't seem like an ideal solution - but I don't know what else you could do.